# Fix Github commits which are not counted

Tags: git, github

I made some commits to github in different times from different clients. Now I see, in my profile some of them don't show up. When I go and check the commit, I can see it there but without my profile picture. From it I understand, this is because of my local configs of clients.

Is there a way I can edit past commits or make the ones with wrong configs show up in my profile ?

EDIT: I can view my commits at github. But ones i made from my mac with profile picture and ones i made from my windows pc, without profile picture. Now i know, when i fix it, my future commits will be counted. What i am asking is what about the past ones ?

Comment: Have you pushed your commits?  Are all the clients operating on the correct branch?

Comment: Yes. Yes. I can view my commits at github. But ones from my mac with profile picture and ones from my windows pc, without profile picture. Now i know when i fix it, my future commits will be counted but i ask "what about past ones ?"

Comment: You can't edit past commits, because the sha is associated with them exactly as they are. You could re-write the history, but this is often a bad idea. If you are the sole contributor, you could do  it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author and committer identity are an integral part of a commit; so to fix existing commits you have to rebase them (that is, replace them with new commits that have the correct metadata).

If anyone else might have `fetch`ed the commit as it exists now (or, more accurately, might have `fetch`ed any ref that can reach the commit as it exists now) then you need to coordinate with all such users.  If there are many other users, or especially if there are users who are in loose communication and might not immediately be aware of what's going on, then it may not be worth the headaches it will cause.  Also the more new work is based on the commit, the higher the cost of editing it.

If you understand the above and still want to fix it, then the best procedure is

1) Get everyone to push all of their work to the remote
2) Get everyone to discard their clones
3) Fix the commits locally
4) Force-push the fix to the remote
5) Everyone can re-clone

If that's impractical, then you can refer to the section "recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` documentation for tips about how each developer can recover without discarding/recloning.

As for how to do the rewrite itself... that again depends on the topology of "other" commits (and refs) that can reach the commit(s) you want to fix.  In the simplest case, if you have

```
A -- x1 -- B -- x2 -- C <--(master)
```

with no other refs, no merges, and nobody already working locally on branches that can reach `x1`, then you can

```
git rebase -i --root master
```

You'll get a TODO list with an entry for each commit; locate `x1` and `x2` and change their command from `pick` to `edit`.  After each commit marked for `edit`, git will pause the rebase.  You can then say

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

(assuming you've fixed your local config).

If there are multiple branches and/or merges, things get more complicated quickly.  Merges that might contain conflict resolutions (or "evil" changes) are a particular problem.  There are *many* variations, so if given the above information you need additional help with a specific situation, then I'd need more information (like a sample commit/ref graph).

Comment: Mark, thanks for your great answer. Since it's too much work and my earlier stuff is not that important, i decided to let it go. As for my last commit(which matters more since it's a pr): i closed the pr, get back to the last good commit, c/p'ed changes, corrected config, pushed and pr'ed again. thanks too much.

Answer (score 3):

Github identifies your commits according to your email address. [Add your second email address to your account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/) and everything should be counted.

Comment: My answer addresses the costs and approach to do what OP asked, but 99% of the point of that is to point out that it probably isn't worth it... which would lead most sane users to this answer.